# How to remove field by key from JSON multiple array in PHP [laravel]

Tags: php, arrays, json, laravel

I`m scratching my head all day and cant figure out. 
Can someone help me please.

I need to make that if all values is null in same column then do not show date and those fields with NULL.

In below example need to remove 2015-09-17 value becouse log1, log2, log3, log4, log5 has empty values in 5 position of that field.

```
0 - column - "2015-09-12"
1 - column - "2015-09-13"
2 - column - "2015-09-14"
3 - column - "2015-09-15"
4 - column - "2015-09-16"
5 - column - "2015-09-17"
6 - column - "2015-09-18"



{
  "error": false,
  "stats": {
    "x": [
      "2015-09-12",
      "2015-09-13",
      "2015-09-14",
      "2015-09-15",
      "2015-09-16",
      "2015-09-17",
      "2015-09-18"
    ],
    "log1": [
      null,
      null,
      null,
      null,
      null,
      null,
      null
    ],
    "log2": [
      "3.0000",
      null,
      null,
      "0.0000",
      "0.7500",
      null,
      "3.0000"
    ],
    "log3": [
      null,
      null,
      null,
      "200",
      null,
      null,
      null
    ],
    "log4": [
      1,
      null,
      null,
      5,
      4,
      null,
      2
    ],
    "log5": [
      null,
      null,
      null,
      null,
      null,
      null,
      null
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: At this moment I was tried to implement new function, just beforepassing JSON, that check all log1, log2 and etc. variables, and if then all variables is null then do not pass that date. But this method is not very good because if user wants to select 300 log entries then it was very long time to wait.

Comment: any help, pls help ?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed problem by using this function:

```
private function array_intersect_by_key_position($model)
{

    $result_array = array_intersect_assoc($model['log1'], $model['log2'], $model['log3'], $model['log4'], $model['log5']);

    //dd($result_array);
    if(count($result_array) > 0)
    {
        foreach($result_array as $res => $val)
        {
            unset($model['x'][$res]);
            unset($model['log1'][$res]);
            unset($model['log2'][$res]);
            unset($model['log3'][$res]);
            unset($model['log4'][$res]);
            unset($model['log5'][$res]);
        }

        $model['x'] = array_values($model['x']);
        $model['log1'] = array_values($model['log1']);
        $model['log2'] = array_values($model['log2']);
        $model['log3'] = array_values($model['log3']);
        $model['log4'] = array_values($model['log4']);
        $model['log5'] = array_values($model['log5']);

        return $model;

    }
    else
    {
        return $model;
    }

}
```